# Почему не вводится значение в поле input? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Проблема, не вводится значение в поле `input`:

```
<input onChange={input.onChange} value={input.value} />
```

У преподавателя даже использовался более современный синтаксис:

```
<input {...input} />
```

но и он не работает.

Заранее благодарю за помощь

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form'

class StreamCreate extends React.Component{
    renderInput({input,label}){
        return (
            <div className="field">
                <label htmlFor="">{label}</label>
                <input onChange={input.onChange} value={input.value}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
   render() {
       return (
           <form className="ui form">
               <Field name="title" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Title"/>
               <Field name="description" component={this.renderInput} label="Enter Description"/>
           </form>
       )
   }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form:'streamCreate',
})(StreamCreate);
```

Comment: Уберите onChange={input.onChange} и должно заработать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Общий принцип работы:

```
const YourComponent = () => {    
    const [value, setValue] = useState()
    
    const handleChange = event => {
       setState(event.target.value)
    }
    
    return <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

Если Вы передаете `state` и `функцию для его изменения` через `props`, то:

```
const anotherComponent = ({ value, handleChange }) => {            
    return <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

Вопрос в том КАК именно Вы передаете что то через `props`?

---

Цитата из комментария автора:

> Вы задали хороший вопрос, я тоже задумался "откуда" на самом деле, и понял что в `combineReducers` не хватает чего-то (...что и решило проблему).

Comment: Вы задали хороший вопрос, я тоже задумался откуда на самом деле и понял что в combineReducers не хватает чего то, оказалось что нужно было передать переменную form. import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form'
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

export default combineReducers({
    auth:authReducer,
    form:formReducer
})